# Best approach for creating databases for sub-sites

Tags: 7, database, performance, subsites

I have to create a website that has about 1000(in future thousands) sub-sites. How should I create database for this sub-sites? Creating a separate database per site, or creating for example 10 databases, each one for 100 sites(using table prefixes), or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each site should have it's own database if possible. The only reason to use table prefixes is if your host limits the number of databases you can create. You can share data without prefixes. Another thing to look into is [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain), if you wish to share a lot of content between the sub sites.

By having separate databases it will allow you to easily scale horizontally; move the DB to a new DB server; if they are all prefixed it makes it a lot harder to move databases to different servers.

Answer (score 1):

The option to use table prefixes exists because some hosting providers limit the number of databases. Don't use this feature unless your hosting provider is one of those.

Comment: What about performance? Which way is better?

Comment: You may also use table prefixes if you need to share some of your tables.